# Can I use WPF window constructor to change culture?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, locbaml

I use the well known **LocBaml** approach to change culture.

It works fine here:

```
public App()
{ 
    // Test code 
    bool override_current_ui_language = true;
    string locale = "es-ES";
    if (override_current_ui_language)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(locale);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(locale);
    }    
}
```

But when I use the same under WPF Window class controller it doesn't work.

Any clue why is it?

---

I use this but it doesn't work as well.

```
void cmbLanguages_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            string locale = "es-ES";
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(locale);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(locale);
        }
```

Comment: I can recommend you http://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com/ where the switching works fine for me...

Comment: @chrfin In fact I use Easy BAML. It's fine as well. What I want is to use wpf combobox to switch languages.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you with "Easy BAML", because I use LocalizeExtension to do exactly that (during runtime)...

Comment: See my answer for an example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [LocalizeExtension](http://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com/) for that.

In the .xaml you just use `{LocText NAMESPACE::RESOURCENAME}` to set the text and in the code behind the following to change the language on the fly:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
LocalizeDictionary.Instance.Culture = culture;
```

You can check my Project on Codeplex, where I use it, to see an extended example:
[XAML](http://moviecollection.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/12597#119931) and [CodeBehind](http://moviecollection.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/12597#119930) (->SetUICulture)

Comment: Thats strange - I use that in several applications. Have you created the correct Resources? `Resources.resx` for english, `Resources.es.resx` for spanish aso.?

Comment: Yeah That was a problem. Thank you bro for a great advice to use WPF Localize Extension project http://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

It should work in the *constructor* if you do it before the `InitalizeComponent()` call, but your example shows an event handler.  Once `InitializeComponent()` is called the BAML has been loaded from the resources and you won't be able to change it.

You can use an approach like the one illustrated here https://www.codeproject.com/articles/29800/webcontrols/ to create a new window with your new culture:

```
void SwitchCulture(CultureInfo newCulture)
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = newCulture;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
    // Reload all the merged dictionaries to reset the resources.
    List<Uri> dictionaryList = new List<Uri>();
    foreach (ResourceDictionary dictionary in Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries)
    {
        dictionaryList.Add(dictionary.Source);
    }
    Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
    foreach (Uri uri in dictionaryList)
    {
        ResourceDictionary resourceDictionary1 = new ResourceDictionary();
        resourceDictionary1.Source = uri;
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add( resourceDictionary1 );
    }

    MyWindowClass newWindow = new MyWiondowClass();
    // TODO: Attach any view model so the new window looks like the old one
    newWindow.Show();
    this.Close();
}
```